# import kernlad model to caret

Tags: r, caret

I'd like to test the *anova rbf kernel* included in the **kernlab** package in **caret**. Following excelent tutorial (https://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html) I've come up with the following code:

```
SVManova <- list(type = "Regression", library = "kernlab", loop = NULL)
prmanova <- data.frame(parameter = c("C", "sigma", "degree", "eps"),
                     class = rep("numeric", 4),
                     label = c("Cost", "Sigma", "Degree", "Eps"))
SVManova$parameters <- prmanova
    svmGridanova <- function(x, y, len = NULL) {
    library(kernlab)
    sigmas <- sigest(as.matrix(x), na.action = na.omit, scaled = TRUE, frac = 1)
    expand.grid(sigma = mean(sigmas[-2]), epsilon = 0.000001,
                C = 2 ^(-5:len), degree = 1:2) # len = tuneLength in train
    }
    SVManova$grid <- svmGridanova
svmFitanova <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {
  ksvm(x = as.matrix(x), y = y,
       kernel = "anovadot",
       kpar = list(sigma = param$sigma, degree = param$degree),
       C = param$C, epsilon = param$epsilon,
       prob.model = classProbs,
       ...) #default type = "eps-svr"
}
SVManova$fit <- svmFitanova
    svmPredanova <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL)
      predict(modelFit, newdata)
    SVManova$predict <- svmPredanova
svmProb <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL)
  predict(modelFit, newdata, type="probabilities")
SVManova$prob <- svmProb
    svmSortanova <- function(x) x[order(x$C), ]
SVManova$sort <- svmSortanova
```

I then asked for the model to train some dataset:

```
set.seed(100) #use the same seed to train different models
svrFitanova <- train(R ~ .,
                data = trainSet,
                method = SVManova,
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 20,
                allowParallel = TRUE) #By default, RMSE and R2 are computed for regression (in all cases, selects the tunning and cross-val model with best value) , metric = "ROC"
#Print the results
svrFitanova
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  The tuning parameter grid should have columns C, sigma, degree, eps
```

I don't see why this error occurs.... tune grid has four columns as requested... Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `svmGridanova`, change the variable name from `epsilon` to `eps`.

Max

Comment: Of course. I also changed `eps` and `Eps` to `epsilon`. Thanks!